# Juno Mission. How better resolution will the optical images be to previous missions?

Tags: jupiter, juno

Resolution in km/pixel at:

(i) the closest approach and (ii) typical when in close to Jupiter part of the eccentric orbit.

Comment: It would seem there is some overlap on the two SE Communities. Knowing resolution provides clues to what sort of new level information will be obtained. So for example cloud dynamics at finer scale. It also provides some perspective of the range of humanity obtained resolution within which amateur and professional observations sit on. These new images extending that scale by a factor of 2, 30 km to 15 km/pixel.  I think it is helpful and relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Juno-cam is designed to achieve about [15km/pixel resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JunoCam), at 4300 km, and proportionately less at greater distance. At closest approach it may achieve [3km/pixel](https://twitter.com/NASAJuno/status/750068514560495616)

This compares with Galileo that had a best resolution of [30km/pixel](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA00720). And [80km/pixel](http://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA01512) for Voyager

The difference for Juno is that Jupiter is the main focus of the mission, whereas Galileo was more about the moons. Juno has more instrumentation for investigating the clouds, magnetosphere and mass distribution of Jupiter. Juno's polar orbit allows close imagery high latitudes that were never imaged by previous missions.